# Splitting values into Units, Thousands, Millions and Billions into columns in a SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to split values into Units, Thousands, Millions and Billions in the SQL Server. The values can be negative and positive and there is not set number of characters/numbers for a value. I arrived to this point:
[image]

So this is my code:

```
UPDATE table
SET Units = RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),[Value]), 3)

UPDATE table
SET Thousands = Right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),[Value]), 6)

UPDATE table
SET Thousands = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Thousands), 1, 3)
```

But here I encounter a problem, as if I have a number '1 019 242', for Units it works -> 242, but for thousands, I first want to have 6 digits from the right: 019242 and then substring first 3 digits, but the 0 is disappearing, so instead of 19 I get 192...

Also I dont know how to do for billions, as the numbers may vary in size, so it can be '19 105' or '37 594 820 583'...

Btw this is just the way I came up with, but maybe there is something easier to do!

Thanks for your help in advance!

I managed (THANKS TO THE COMMENTS!, thank you) to arrive at the point:
[image]

Now I am trying to save the results to my column Thousands. Not sure how to do it, I am looking it up..

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Do you really need to do this in the *database*? This sort of work is usually better done in you presentation layer/report builder.

Comment: Thank you, I will look up other solutions as well :) I cannot fully freely choose which app/program I am using for this..

Answer (score 4):

A mix of integer math and mod should get you want you want

```
SELECT  A.Value,
        ABS(A.Value) / 1000000000 AS Billions,
        ABS(A.Value) % 1000000000 / 1000000 AS Millions,
        ABS(A.Value) % 1000000 / 1000 AS Thousands,
        ABS(A.Value) % 1000 AS Units,
        CASE WHEN A.Value < 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END AS New_Col
FROM    (
            VALUES (CAST(3070192242 AS BIGINT)),(-370192242)
        ) AS A(Value);
```

[% (Modulus) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[ABS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Edit:

Update statement:

```
UPDATE  A
SET     Billions = ABS(A.Value) / 1000000000,
        Millions = ABS(A.Value) % 1000000000 / 1000000,
        Thousands = ABS(A.Value) % 1000000 / 1000,
        Units = ABS(A.Value) % 1000,
        New_Col = CASE WHEN A.Value < 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END AS New_Col
FROM    dbo.YourTable AS A;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Now I just have a memory problem with my database, but I am trying to split those functions as it works like this. I am doing: SELECT [Value],   ABS(Value) % 1000000 / 1000 AS Thousands, FROM table. I do not know how to save those Thousands into my column in my table yet, I am trying it out now!

Comment: Thank you!!! This works, you just need to have enough space on your disk, or the file should be small! :) Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
update [table] set
     [units]        =   abs([value] % 1000) 
    ,[thousands]    =   abs([value] % 1000000 / 1000)
    ,[millions]     =   abs([value] % 1000000000 / 1000000) 
    ,[billions]     =   abs([value] % 1000000000000 / 1000000000)   
    ,[new_col]          =   sign([value])
```

And, if you have log file grow problems, try cyclic approach, it uses less log space:

```
while exists (select null from [table] where [units] is null)
begin
    update top(1) percent [table] set
         [units]        =   abs([value] % 1000) 
        ,[thousands]    =   abs([value] % 1000000 / 1000)
        ,[millions]     =   abs([value] % 1000000000 / 1000000) 
        ,[billions]     =   abs([value] % 1000000000000 / 1000000000)   
        ,[sign]         =   sign([value])
    where [units] is null

end;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as well! But I get error: The transaction log for database 'database_name' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'... Even if I split the function just for one line (to update only Thousands for example..)

Comment: Your table has a lot records? Or, maybe you performed heavy data manipulation tasks before? Try to shrink log file: right click on database> tasks > shrink >files> choose file type "log", reorgaize pages...

Comment: Thank you I am trying this, as well as increasing a database size! Yes, it has 125 000 rows plus I am adding columns now (it has 8 columns at the moment).

Comment: I added cyclic update query to my original answer. It is more log file growth friendly. Please try :)

Comment: Thanks!!!! This time it performed the function without any problem, but the Columns are not affected! :( I tried for now only for Units and thousands, but there is no change when I look at top few hundred rows!

Comment: Anyways, it works if you have a smaller file or more space, thanks!!

Comment: Second query works with [units] IS NULL field only. You need to adapt where/while loop clauses by your needs

Comment: IT WORKED!!! I was increasing size of a wrong file in my SQL Manager!! Now it can perform your query!!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use computed fields. These fields use **no space** in your database, so file size should not be an issue. And you are not required to set them or update them.

```
create table BigVal ( [Value] int,
Billions as abs([Value] / 1000000000 ),
Millions as abs([Value] % 1000000000 / 1000000),
Thousands as abs([Value] % 1000000 / 1000),
Units as abs([Value] % 1000),
[Sign] as case when Value < 0 then -1 else 1 end )

insert into BigVal ( [Value] ) values
(         234 ),
(      123456 ),
(   123456789 ),
(  1234567890 ),
(         -23 ),
( -1234567890 ),
(  2147483647 ),
( -2147483648 )

select * from BigVal
```

Results are:

```
Value       Billions    Millions    Thousands   Units       Sign
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
234         0           0           0           234         1
123456      0           0           123         456         1
123456789   0           123         456         789         1
1234567890  1           234         567         890         1
-23         0           0           0           23          -1
-1234567890 1           234         567         890         -1
2147483647  2           147         483         647         1
-2147483648 2           147         483         648         -1
```

Comment: At first glance it would appear that "abs([Value]) / 1000000000" and "abs([Value] / 1000000000 )" should have identical results.  They do, except for the lowest negative value, -2147483648.  Calling ABS on this value fails.

Answer (score 0):

Pad it with space in-front (on the left) after you have convert to string.

Than thousand is always `LEFT ( RIGHT ( VALUE , 6) , 3)`

```
thousands   = left(right(space(10) + convert(varchar(100), [value]), 6), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

THANKS EVERYONE!!

So the queries mentioned above in the comments work for me, and if the database size is not enough, increase it (the log file) and it will work.